# Is there a way to make a woocommerce plugin work offline

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, create-react-native-app

I've installed a woocommerce based plugin(woocommerce point of sale) and i want the logged  in user to place an order even if there's no internet connection, and then the order will automatically be synced in once the internet connection is back.

Answer (score 0):

I mean theoretically you can always do that by saving all the information and send the request later.  But there's a lot of legal and technical issues with this.  For example:

- Are they using a credit card?  Saving credit card numbers like that is not allowed by PCI standards and will get you either sued when there's a breach or lose your payment processor.
- What happens if the request fails?  The buyer is long gone.

I have made systems that did this (not using woocommerce, but using our own tech).  But that was for wholesale, where the order is confirmed and paid for in its own workflow and not done immediately (and generally not paid by credit card).  I think it would be very difficult to make this work for consumer commerce unless its a buy now pay later type sale.  I'd really consider hard if this is actually a good idea for your business.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, in fact the users of the system are not the consumers but the vendors, and no actual payment is made it's just for confirming the orders... what i'm trying to say is thaat the payment bit is not an issue here, i only need the implant an offline mode.